# Playwright. How to skip all tests in a group if selector not found?

Tags: angular, e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-test, angular-e2e

I am developing E2E tests with [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/docs/intro) for [angular](https://angular.io/) app. I have to ensure that needed conditional selector exists in order to proceed, otherwise skip further tests.

In other words I need to skip all tests in a group if `await page.isVisible('button[id=container]')` condition is not satisfied in `beforeAll` hook.

The problem is that only the first test is being skipped and the second one is being passed(which is wrong). Please check screenshot below.

Here is the code:

```
test.describe.serial('Products ', () => {
  let page: Page;
  test.beforeAll(async ({ browser, baseURL }) => {
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(baseURL as string, opt);

    if (await page.isVisible('button[id=container]')) {
      await page.locator('button[id=container]').click();
    } else {
      console.log('Error: Container tab is not loaded...');
      test.skip();
    }
  });
  test.only('Check if "Menu" tab is available', async () => {
    ... test goes here ...
  });
  test.only('Check if Orders page is available', async () => {
    ... test goes here ...
  });

});
```

[image]

The interesting thing is that playwright skips all tests when `beforeEach` hook is used instead, but I would like to achieve this result within `beforeAll` hook.

Answer (score 1):

That is interesting behavior, and maybe because inside a hook like beforeAll it’s treating it as a single test skip, whereas calling it outside any hooks or tests but within a describe block skips all the tests in that block. Not sure though.

My first solution to offer is based off your intent. Do you really want them to skip? Or should it not reach that point and actually be a failure and just fail all the tests in that group? You could just throw an error inside the beforeAll, like so:

```js
throw new Error('Error: Container tab is not loaded...')
```

Or better yet, get rid of the if else all together, and just let the click error, which already checks actionability like being visible and takes advantage of auto-waiting. And if you still want the custom error message, wrap it in a try catch block where the catch does that console error and then rethrows the error. Or do an `expect(locator, message).toBeVisible()` first with the [custom message option](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#custom-expect-message), which still gives the auto-wait benefit.

If you are bent on skipping though, one option would be to use a ”flag”/boolean variable that you declare in the describe and set in the beforeAll, and then all the [tests conditionally skip](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-skip-3) off that. Not as great as having skip in the beforeAll skip all the tests, but a workaround that should do the trick.

Comment: I would like to skip tests because don't want to break CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: Okay, I can see that reason, I guess I just don’t understand fully understand though since if it’s not behaving as it should, shouldn’t that break the deploy, just like your other tests? Or if it’s just flaky but the app is fine, sounds like the issue is the flakiness needs to be fixed, rather than just ignored and hope it’s fine. That all being said, whether I’m missing context or whatever your reason is, I did give an option for if you really want to skip. Does that not solve it for you, or do you need me to improve the answer?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am looking for something else.